# Which javascript function like parsefloat that takes the locale as parameter?

Tags: javascript

Problem:

I got this input:

```
"23,234.34"
```

with the following locale, 
locale = "us-US"

I want this result : `23234.34` in number var.

So i use parseFloat but this function don't take a locale as parameter, 
When i use the string "23,234.34", the function return Not a number (NAN).

```
if ($('input#feesamount').val() != '') {
            $funding = {
              feeAmount: parseFloat($('input#feesamount').val()),
              acquirerregistrationid: $('input#registerid').val(),
              acquirer: $('select#acquirer').val()
            };
```

Do you know a function who can help me ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12694511/

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript parseFloat in Different Cultures](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12694455/javascript-parsefloat-in-different-cultures)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are only dealing with US formats, you can just use `string.replace(/,/g, '')`. Otherwise, you want to use this library : http://numeraljs.com/

Comment: How do you get the number inside the input with numeraljs?

Answer (score 0):

You could write your own that uses a `switch` to process the price/fee depending on locale and returns a float.

```
var price = '23,234.34';
var locale = 'us-US';

function parsePrice(price, locale) {
    switch (locale) {
        case 'us-US':
            price = price.replace(',', '');
            break;
    }
    return parseFloat(price);
}

parsePrice(price, locale); // 23234.34
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/f7wvqLrs/)

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace the ',' with ''(Empty String)

```
if ($('input#feesamount').val() != '') {
        $funding = {
          feeAmount: parseFloat(($('input#feesamount').val()).replace(/,/g,'')),
          acquirerregistrationid: $('input#registerid').val(),
          acquirer: $('select#acquirer').val()
        };
```