# Round float and then to locale string

Tags: javascript

I have some strange example.
If I write this:

```
parseFloat("12345,987").toLocaleString("slv")
```

the result would be as expected(slv has comma as decimal separator):
12.345,987

But if I round first to 2 decimals:

```
parseFloat("12345,987").toFixed(2).toLocaleString("slv")
```

the result would be always with english separator(dot):
`12,345.99`

How is that possible?
It should be: `12.345,99`

Comment: The output of parseFloat is a number, the output of toFixed is a string.

Answer (score 4):

As described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12694511/120497), `parseFloat()` is meant to be used with decimals only and therefore passing in a string with commas can lead to unexpected results.

For example, I tried `parseFloat("12345,987").toLocaleString("slv")` in JsFiddle and my browser (UK locale) gave me `12.345`, which is different to your result.

One other point to note is that `toFixed()` returns a string but `toLocaleString()` operates on numbers. Applying `toLocaleString()` to a string might also produce unexpected results for a different reason.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you. I have found a solution:
parseFloat("12345,987").toLocaleString("slv", { minimumFractionDigits: 2, maximumFractionDigits: 2 });

This works ok.
"For example, I tried parseFloat("12345,987").toLocaleString("slv")"

"djskinner" - Can you try with: "sl-SI" instead of slv? Does it still doesn't work?