# ParseFloat not working

Tags: javascript

i am trying to parse a float in javascript in this way:

```
var number = '25.492.381';

var cost = parseFloat(number);
```

This returns 25.492

I wish this would return 25.492.381

How can this be done?

Comment: Numbers don't work like that. If you really want `25.492.381`, just keep the string.

Comment: I've never seen a number have two decimal points

Comment: you want fractional part of the fractional part?

Comment: The `.` is the decimal point. You can not have a number with two decimal points. If you want to parse this, you have to remove the dots first (assuming those are actually meant to be thousand separators.)

Comment: This shows how parseFloat works... https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parsefloat.asp

Comment: @all in some countrys, the normal number notation is 199.234.222,123 which is confusing for programmers the first time.

Comment: In Europe, numbers are formatted like this: €1.234.567,89.  See https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/9105/international-currency-formatting-guidelines-currency-codes

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript parseFloat in Different Cultures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12694455/javascript-parsefloat-in-different-cultures)

Answer (score 3):

Remember that `.` in standard notation split the Integer and Fractional part of the number. You could want this:

```
var number = '25.492.381'.replace('.', '').replace(",",".") ;

var cost = parseFloat(number);
```

Comment: `parseFloat('25492381')` doesn't seem very useful to me (since it's an integer anyway).

Comment: @byxor if he adds .replace(",",".") it will be useful

Answer (score 1):

25.492.381 is not a `float`. You need to use a formatter.
Check [Numbro](http://numbrojs.com/format.html)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/16497697)

Comment: I understand but I don't know which format fit for him.