# Convert float number properly?

Tags: javascript

How can I convert this string to get `1000000`? The problem is I always get `10000`:

```js
console.log(parseFloat('10.000.000,00'.replace('.', ',').replace(/,(?=[^,]*$)/, '.')),'test');
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Replace decimal with empty string, and then comma with decimal?

Comment: switch the order of the replace statemets

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12694455/javascript-parsefloat-in-different-cultures

Comment: You should try the replace on paper first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
parseFloat(a.replace(/\./g, '').replace(',', '.'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
parseFloat('10.000.000,00'.replace(/\./g, '').replace(',', '.'), 10)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do: 
`'10.000.000,00'.split(',')[0].replace(/\./g,'');`

So, in this case, you can use it for *any* decimal value after the `,` so if you wish later to add this value, you can get it with `[1]` location returned by `split`.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```js
/** German number format info */
const numberFomatInfoDeDe = {
  decimalSeparator: ",",
  numberGroupSeparator: ".",
};

/**
 * Converts a string to a number.
 * @param str The string to convert.
 * @param numberFomatInfo Information for the conversion.
 * @returns The number. NaN if the string cannot be converted.
 */
function stringToNumber(str, numberFomatInfo) {
  let tmp = str;

  tmp = tmp.replace(new RegExp("\\" + numberFomatInfo.numberGroupSeparator, "g"), "");
  tmp = tmp.replace(numberFomatInfo.decimalSeparator, ".");

  return parseFloat(tmp);
}

// Tests
console.log(stringToNumber("10.000.000,00", numberFomatInfoDeDe));
console.log(stringToNumber("10,00", numberFomatInfoDeDe));
console.log(stringToNumber("-10", numberFomatInfoDeDe));
console.log(stringToNumber("asdf", numberFomatInfoDeDe));
```

Answer (score -1):

your code probably isn't doing what you seem to be expecting it to do.  you should try running each sub-expression separately in a debugger, i.e:

```
'10.000.000,00'.replace('.', ',')
```

gives back `"10,000.000,00"`, i.e. just the first period is replaced by a comma, while:

```
"10,000.000,00".replace(/,(?=[^,]*$)/, '.')
```

evaluates to: `"10,000.000.00"`, i.e. the last comma is replaced by a period.  you then do:

```
parseFloat("10,000.000.00")
```

which evaluates to 10.

note that you can also pass a function to the `replace` function which can be used as:

```
'10.000.000,00'.replace(/[.,]/g, m => ({'.':'', ',':'.'}[m]))
```

which makes a single pass over the string, removing periods and replacing commas with periods